# Google Charts Dashboard - newbie can't get final row of data to be recognized as a number

Tags: javascript, csv, charts, dashboard, pygooglechart

Here's my code - if I change 'Exports' column to a number, my HTML page will not load, giving the error message that the first number is not recognized as a number. Is the CSV transformation process not recognizing the final row as a number, and how do I fix this? Thanks!!!

```
function drawDashboard() {
$.get("/static/data/HS2-b.csv", function(csvString) {
     // transform the CSV string into a 2-dimensional array
     //
     var castLastColAsNum = function(data) {
         for (var row in data) {
             row[-1] = parseInt(row[-1]);
         }
         return data;
     };

     var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {
         onPostParse: castLastColAsNum
         // onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar
     });

     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
     // data.addColumn('string', 'NAICS Code');
     data.addColumn('string', 'HS');
     data.addColumn('string', 'DESCRIPTION');
     data.addColumn('string', 'COUNTRY');
     data.addColumn('string', 'STATE'); 
     data.addColumn('string', 'EXPORTS');
     // console.log(arrayData);
     data.addRows(arrayData);
```

Comment: and I meant final "column" of data...